# Calculating Dynamic Monthly Targets in DAX / BI

Tags: database-design, powerbi, dax

I've got some data on monthly targets I need to meet and I'm wondering how I can get this working dynamically with the tables I have. There are a handful of checklists that I need to run a report on, but some are Multiple times daily, Weekly or monthly.

I have the 2 tables below in power query.

[image]

[image]

I needed to be able to return the Monthly target for each checklist depending on the number of working days (days in table 1).

For example

Forklift Febuary 2022 target = 38

Defibrillator Feb 2022 target = 4

These checklists will change yearly, so I'm trying to avoid hardcoding it as much as possible. Are there any DAX queries or similar to help me achieve this?

Comment: Is the February "days" column incorrect?  If not, how are you computing 38 for the Forklift Feb 2022 target?  Also, how do you envision your output appearing?  You could, for example, have a column for Years, and then multiple columns for each month.

Comment: Hi Ron, 
There are 2 Forklift checks daily, and 19 working days. Thats how I came up with the 38 total. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

**Edit** I see why you asked. Yes I was said Feb but meant Jan =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this using Power Query (In Power BI `Home=Transform Data`)

*Join the two tables on Year and compute the necessary value*

***M Code**
 Paste into Advanced Editor
First four lines may need editing depending on your actual data source*

```
let

//read in the two tables
// change next four lines according to your actual data sources
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Checklists"]}[Content],
    Checklists = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Checklist Type", type text}, {"Quantity", Int64.Type}, {"Frequency", type text}}),

    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Months"]}[Content],
    Months = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2, 
        List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Source2),{Date.Type,Text.Type,Int64.Type,Int64.Type,Int64.Type}})),

//Join the tables on year
//  If there will only be a single year in your table, then don't need to join
    Joined = Table.NestedJoin(Checklists,"Year", Months,"Year","Joined",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    Targets = Table.AddColumn(Joined, "Target", each Record.FromList(
            List.Accumulate(
                {0..11},
                {},
                (state, current)=> state & 
                    {if [Frequency] = "Day"  then [Quantity] * [Joined][Days]{current} 
                        else if [Frequency] = "Week" then [Quantity] * [Joined][Weeks]{current}
                        else if [Frequency] = "Month" then [Quantity]
                        else "Frequency Error"}), [Joined][Month])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Targets,{"Joined"}),
    #"Expanded Target" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Target", 
                            List.Distinct(Months[Month]), 
                            List.Transform(List.Distinct(Months[Month]), each "Target." & _)),
    #"Set Data Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Target", 
        List.Transform(
            List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Target"),4), 
            each {_, Int64.Type}))
in
    #"Set Data Types"
```

[image]

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! one quick question. If I wanted to use this with the slicer in power bi is there a way your familiar with?

Comment: @DylanBenton I don't know anything special.  If you are having a problem, I'd suggest clarifying it and probably posing it as a new question.  What were you trying to do?  and what problems did you run into?

Comment: Thanks Ron, I just posted a separate question :)